# Problema de reseteo de Google App Engine usando Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Buenas,
tengo un problema que no sé ni por donde empezar con varias aplicaciones en Google App Engine usando Java.

Resulta que de repente la aplicación vuelve a una versión anterior de la que tenía instalada, perdiendo textos del DataStore y ficheros del cloud storage.

Al borrarse el Datasore, tengo un listener que si está vacío el DataStore lo vuelve a rellenar con datos iniciales, pero no es el caso ya que la última versión subida tiene otros textos. Así que creo que no es solo el datastore y el cloud storage, sino que me parece que toda la aplicación de Google App Engine se restaurara de una imagen de varios meses atrás.
Tengo la impresión de que se pone la última versión subida y que se borran todos los textos y ficheros que había desde entonces.

No sé lo que pasa y cuando he visto el problema, no he llegado a tiempo para ver en el log (ya que se borran los registros antiguos al de pocos días).

Agradecería cualquier pista que me pudieseis dar ya que no sé ni por donde empezar.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Es algo muy raro lo que te pasa, estas diciendo que la versión desplegada vuelve a versiones anteriores sola? Como haces un Listener para el datastore en una aplicación que se apaga y prende constantemente? Un poco de codigo ayudaria mucho a ver que esta pasando.

Comment: El listerner solo se ejecuta si la bbdd está vacía, sino no hace nada, es de tipo ServletContextListener y hace comprobaciones de este tipo:
<code>ProductosManager oProductosManager= ProductosManager.getProductosManager();
if (!oProductosManager.hayProducto()) {</code>

Creo que el listener no hace nada raro, lo que quería decir es que el contenido de la página es diferente del backup que se cargaría al estar la bbdd vacía, así que no se ha vaciado la bbdd y se ha ejecutado el backup sino que es como si una versión anterior se instalara. Por eso creo que es algo más general.

Comment: Gracias por contestar :)
A mi me parece que es como si un usuario entrara con una sesión antigua y se restaurara el contenido que había en dicha sesión o algo así.

Comment: por favor inclui el código del listener y lo que uses para leer y escribir en la BD.

Comment: gracias por las molestias y perdona no contestar antes. No he solucionado el problema, pero he cambiado de versión del datastore y a ver si funciona mejor.